# Connect to flask over public connection

Tags: python, flask

I have flask running on my Macbook (10.9.1 if it makes a difference). I have no problem accessing what I have hosted there over my local network, but I'm trying to see if I can access it publicly. For example load a webpage on my iPhone over it's 3G connection. It doesn't appear to be as simple as /index.

With my limited knowledge, my public IP seems to be the one for our internet connection, moreso my own laptop. Is that what is causing the issue?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your router to forward the relevant port to your laptop.

Comment: OK Cool. So Flask tells me it's listening on port 5000, but my router is looking for an inbound port and a private port. I guess the private port should be 5000? what would the inbound be? 80 because it's a HTTP connection?

Comment: You can use 5000 for both, as long as you request :5000 in your browser. The main thing to set is the internal IP, which should be the private IP of the MacBook (you should be able to find that from the router's network page or on the MacBook's Network Preferences).